# Is the maximum of a function over a compact set differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function with respect to both $x,y$. $f$ can be as smooth as is needed for the situation below.

I am considering a function $g(x) = \max_{y \in [a,b]} f(x,y)$.

Is $g$ differentiable? If so, is there a way to compute its derivative analytically?

Comment: In general, no. But it is differentiable ae. (Rademacher theorem). As a simple example, $g(x) = \max_{y \in [0,1]} (y x - (1-y)x) = |x|$ which is not differentiable.

Comment: Look up "envelope theorem"